# Android programming - getBroadacast() method

Tags: android

My book says that getBroadcast() method takes four parameters: Context, RequestCode, Intent, Flags. What do "RequestCode" and "Flags" mean ? What are their purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RequestCode`

> It is used to uniquely identify from which the broadcast was sent also known as Private request code for the sender.

```
Flag
```

> It is used to to control which unspecified parts of the intent that can be supplied when the actual send happens.

It is used to indicate the proper behavior of [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

like flag [FLAG_ONE_SHOT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT) if the described PendingIntent does not already exist, then simply return null instead of creating it.

Refer the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)